# Espresso Intents Custom Intent Matcher

Tags: android-espresso

How do I create a custom matcher for an Intent, so that I can see the contents of it and figure out why my "intended" code matcher is failing?

Answer (score 0):

```
     intended(allOf(new TypeSafeMatcher<Intent>() {
       @Override
       protected boolean matchesSafely(Intent item) {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public void describeTo(Description description) {

       }
   },
```